# What is meant by spatially multimode states of light?

Tags: laser, quantum-optics

I came across this term while reading texts on Quantum Optics and Lasers. While I know something about multimode laser oscillations, I am unsure about what is exactly meant by multimode light?

Comment: Multi-mode implies many different frequencies. Two-mode means two frequencies and so on.

Comment: @suresh How does a laser exhibit multimode effects then? Isn't a laser supposed to emit at a particular frequency?